# Power-Bi plot in multiple layers

Tags: powerbi, histogram

I need help in Power-Bi plot.

I have a dataset consists of 2 columns, named col1 , col2

```
col1  |   col2
1     |    a
1     |    b
1     |    a
2     |    a
2     |    c
```

Now, I draw a chart which shows the histogram of col2 based on unique values of col1.
So the result is :   a:2,  b:1, c:1

Now, I want to have plot, that when I click on "a" value on histogram, shows me the values in col2 which have the common value of "col1" with "a".

I mean here the "a" value has values "1" and "2" in col1. So, When I click on "a" in histogram, I want to see that "b" and "c" has common value of "col1" with "a" and also the number of common values should be shown.

would you please help me to plot this in powerBi?